# Using C Preprocessor to Determine Compilation Environment

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

I am building an application that consists of both a windows driver written in **C** and a user mode executable in C++.  They both use a shared header file to define several macros, constants, enums, etc.  In the C++ version, I want to include everything within a namespace, which a feature not supported by the **C** compiler.  Is there certain variable I can check for to use as a preprocessor directive with Visual Studio like in the following example?

```
#ifdef USING_CPLUSPLUS
namespace mynamespace{
#endif

    struct mystruct{
       ...
    };


#ifdef USING_CPLUSPLUS
}
#endif
```

Comment: in this case, you should probably just declare `mynamespace_mystruct' as a c struct (then maybe typedef `mystruct' within `mynamespace'). otherwise, `mynamespace::mystruct' and `mystruct' are different types… which will just make for a bunch of weird conditional code for people using the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the specific example of distinguishing a C++ compiler from a C compiler, the sensible choice is the macro `__cplusplus` which is defined by the C++ standard to exist, and due to <strike>side effects of the reserved name rules</strike> a clause that says so in standard C, will never be predefined by the C compiler.

Every compiler has a collection of predefined macros that are occasionally useful for distinguishing among compilation hosts and target platforms. One large repository of such macros is the [Predef Project](http://predef.sourceforge.net/) where they are collecting reports on as many combinations of compiler, host, and target as they can.

**Edit:** Clarifying the reserved nature of `__cplusplus` in C: The C standard has always reserved identifiers that begin with two underscores or one underscore followed by a capital letter. For instance, C99 in section 7.1.3 says

> "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.",

and several other clauses carry a footnote that reads in part

> "Implementation-defined keywords shall have the form of an identifier reserved for any use as described in 7.1.3."

So, without any further direction from the standard, in a compliant implementation of a C compiler the name `__cplusplus` is reserved for any use. That name was chosen by the implementors of C++ specifically because it was reserved in C, has a clear meaning, and was not known to have been defined by any C implementation.

However, by C99 the standards committee had decided to make sure that no C implementation damaged the obvious utility of a macro that could be used to distinguish a C compilation from a C++ compilation. In C99 section 6.10.8 they write:

> "The implementation shall not predefine the macro _ _cplusplus, nor shall it define it
>   in any standard header."

Its hard to get more clear than that.

Comment: Where does the C standard declare that such a name can't be a macro? It does say that it's reserved for any use by the implementation.

Comment: @potatoswatter, C99 identified it specifically in 6.10.8. I did not know that before looking for the clause that talks about `__` and `_` followed by caps.

Answer (score 8):

The closest macro I can think of is:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
```

Comment: That would be the exact answer, yes. ;)