# How to check (via the preprocessor) if a C source file is being compiled as C++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

The question title should say it all, but here's an example of what sort of thing I'm looking for:

```
#ifndef THE_IDENTIFIER_THAT_WOULD_INDICATE_BEING_COMPILED_AS_CPLUSPLUS

/*
 * Example of something that would matter.
 */
typedef enum _bool bool;
enum _bool { false, true };

#endif
```

What is the identifier? It's bugging me severely, as I know I've seen code that does this before.

I'm using GCC, by the way.

(I'm surprised I couldn't find a duplicate somewhere on SO. If someone else can find one, feel free to redirect me and close this as a dupe.)

Comment: It's `__cplusplus`. The macro is defined by C++ compilers. Duplicated from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858308/using-c-preprocessor-to-determine-compilation-environment

Comment: btw: C99 added a native boolean type called `_Bool`, aliased to `bool` if you include `<stdbool.h>`

Comment: See also [Preprocessor directive to test if this is C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548490/preprocessor-directive-to-test-if-this-is-c-or-c) to learn about `extern "C"` and some ways to handle.

Comment: I find it amusing that 6 answers and a comment that states the answer all hit enter at the same time: `Nov 10 '10 21:27`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
```

If I remember correctly.

Comment: it's typically used in the header file guards #ifdef __cplusplus\n extern "C" { \n#endif

Comment: +1 You remember correctly. Should be #ifndef for what William wants.

Answer (score 7):

The identifier is `__cplusplus`

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#error NO C++ PLEASE
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

`#ifdef __cplusplus`

with a few really ancient compilers (early versions of cfront and a couple of ports) it was `c_pluplus`, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
```

Answer (score 2):

`#ifdef __cplusplus`

I think the file extension matters too, if the C++ compiler is given a .c file it will compile it as C code. i have nothing to back this up though.

Answer (score 1):

The identifier you are looking for is `__cplusplus`, which can be used like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// Code being compiled as C++.
#endif
```